# Using regex in python to parse log files to extract values

Tags: python, regex, parsing

-- Edited to remove `cols` parameter which was from a previous attempt at parsing these files which I failed to remove from my minimum working example.

I'm trying to parse a log file with text time like what is below using python so that I can see how things like `filament current` change between log files.

```
Format               : GPF: internal memory mode
Shape Type           : TRAPEZIUM
Number of Blocks     : 45
Main field placement : FLOATING
Sub field placement  : LOWERLEFT
Fracture style       : SUBFIELD
Number of Main bits  : 20
Number of Sub bits   : 14
Work Level           : 1
Number freq. factors : 42
Minimum frequency    : 0.671637
Maximum frequency    : 1.009999
Reference frequency    : 0x80000000
Pixel time           : 18852175201.000000 (1.88522e+10)
High Tension         : 100 kV
Block size           :       500.00000000 um,      500.00000000 um
Pattern size         :     60405.86000000 um,    60459.00000000 um
Resolution           :         0.00100000 um
Beamstepsize         :         0.01000000 um
Main resolution      :         0.00100000 um
Trap resolution      :         0.00050000 um


Archive: 10na_300um.beam_100             Date: 26-MAR-2023 
Version Beam      4.00

High Tension           :      100 kV     Final Aperture      :      300 um

Gun control :
bias voltage           :  -400.00  V     filament current    :     2.31  A
Extractor   voltage    :  6200.00  V     current             :   190.78 uA
tilt  X         25857  :  -28.820 mA     tilt  Y      40904  :   31.591 mA
shift X         37124  :   16.916 mA     shift Y      29171  :   -7.572 mA
AD setpoint dac 100kV  :     4095

Lens control:
Final lens      47660  :  4.14551  A
C1 setting      23871  : 4774.200  V     C2 setting    7020  :  1.01707  A

Beam quality:
Fine Focus dac         :     2337
Diagonal Stigmator dac :     1813        Axis Stigmator dac  :     1868

measured spotsize      :    0.024 um     beamcurrent         :    10.27 nA
PMHV setting (dac)     :     2602
BEAMPAR setting        :    300.0 s

Beam diameter       :           26 nm ,           28 nm  current : 10.106 nA

resolution          :     1.000000 nm ,     1.000000 nm
beam step size      :    10.000000 nm ,    10.000000 nm
main resolution     :     1.000000 nm ,     1.000000 nm  [1,1]
trap resolution     :     0.500000 nm ,     0.500000 nm  [20,20]
max. main field size:  1048.576000 um ,  1048.576000 um
max. trap field size:     4.525000 um ,     4.525000 um
tdd shift           :            3666 ,            3666

main compensation               x:  500.000 um    y:  500.000 um

trap compensation               x:    4.525 um    y:    4.525 um

the deflection compensation settings:
                               main     rel  trapezium  rel  pull-in
                             (12bits)         (12bits)      (12bits)
x gain     [bit]       :       2039       0    3331       0    578
y gain     [bit]       :       2068       0    3247       0    738
x rotation [bit]       :       1992       0    2120       0   2061
y rotation [bit]       :       2242       0    1605       0   1588
x keystone [bit]       :       1302       0
y keystone [bit]       :       2045       0

table translation settings      x:    0.000 um    y:    0.000 um
main beam deflection settings   x:    0.000 um    y:    0.000 um

the deflection compensation sensitivities:
(with respect to centre of the deflection field)
                              main       trapezium     pull-in
                             (12bits)     (12bits)    (12bits)
x gain     [ppm/bit]   :      2.442       12.963      19.004
y gain     [ppm/bit]   :      2.439       12.932      18.331
x rotation [ppm/bit]   :      4.908        5.828      38.192
y rotation [ppm/bit]   :      4.907        5.744      38.297
x keystone [ppm/mm/bit]:      1.487
y keystone [ppm/mm/bit]:      1.480
Calculated frequencies:
  Base frequency   :    1.2633 MHz
  Maximum frequency:    1.2759 MHz
  Minimum frequency:  848.4536 kHz


the last adjust main comp height @ relative position ***,*** um : 
22.600 um
Spot defocussed with FL 0 bits
Spot defocussed with FFOFFSET 0 bits

pg information dcd
Last restored file: /home/pg/archive/perftest.dcd_100
Date: 20:46 30-MAR-2023

Main:               Trap:               Stigmator:      SEM:
mddx2    2131,1746  tddxx    2098,1945  fspascor  2047  dcvmdmzoom    1
mddy2    2139,2293  tddxy    2074,2065  fspdscor  2047  dcvmdmpan     0,   0
mddxy2   1717,1686  tddxxy   2059,1982  fspffcor  2047  mdpsem     2367,1983
mddyx2   2427,1574  tddxx2   2101,2188  fspasfunc    0  dcvmdmstep   32
mddx3    1821,1776  tddxy2   2157,2127  fspdsfunc    0  dcvmdmrate    4
mddy3    2344,1757  tddyx    2052,2216  fspfffunc    0
mddorth  2040,2238  tddyy    1949,1989  dcvdc       31
mdpgain  1619,2427  tddyxy   2056,2023
mdpvout  3279,1041  tddyx2   2017,2065
mdpslow     0,   0  tddyy2   2060,2100
Beam Blanker:                           Pattern Generator:
bbsmode             PN                  beamondelay          0.00_ns
bbshvadjust         80.00_%,80.00_%     beamoffdelay        10.00_ns
bbszeroadjust        0.00_%, 0.00_%     negativecommondelay 25.00_ns

mbsbase             50000_ns            sbsbase               500_ns
mbsfactor             100_ns/um         sbsfactor             500_ns/um
mbsfocus             1000_ns/um
```

I've written the following code using `re` try and extract all the data separated by a colon.

```
fname = 'example.log'


colon_data = r'\s*(\S*\s*\S*\s*\S*)\s*:\s*(\S*\s*\S*)\s*|\n'


pat = re.compile(colon_data)

with open(fname, encoding='utf8') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()


data_dict = {}
for line in contents:
    if re.match(colon_data,line):
        data_dict[re.match(colon_data,line).groups()[0]] = re.match(colon_data,line).groups()[1]


data_dict

``

Which gives me the output below, which is close to what I want but it gets tripped up on cases such as `bias voltage           :  -400.00  V     filament current    :     2.31  A` where it only recognised the first value in the line and not the second. It also interprets everything as strings and it'd be nice to recognise floats as floats. Can anyone suggest how I might fix this?
```

{'Format               : GPF': 'internal memory',
'Shape Type           ': 'TRAPEZIUM\n',
'Number of Blocks': '45\n',
'Main field placement': 'FLOATING\n',
'Sub field placement': 'LOWERLEFT\n',
'Fracture style       ': 'SUBFIELD\n',
'Work Level           ': '1\n',
'Number freq. factors': '42\n',
'Minimum frequency    ': '0.671637\n',
'Maximum frequency    ': '1.009999\n',
'Reference frequency    ': '0x80000000\n',
'Pixel time           ': '18852175201.000000 (1.88522e+10)',
'High Tension         ': '100 kV',
'Block size           ': '500.00000000 um,',
'Pattern size         ': '60405.86000000 um,',
'Resolution           ': '0.00100000 um',
'Beamstepsize         ': '0.01000000 um',
'Main resolution      ': '0.00100000 um',
'Trap resolution      ': '0.00050000 um',
None: None,
'Archive: 10na_300um.beam_100             Date': '26-MAR-2023 \n',
'High Tension           ': '100 kV',
'Gun control ': '',
'bias voltage           ': '-400.00  V',
'Extractor   voltage    ': '6200.00  V',
'tilt  X         25857': '-28.820 mA',
'shift X         37124': '16.916 mA',
'Lens control': '',
'Final lens      47660': '4.14551  A',
'C1 setting      23871': '4774.200  V',
'Beam quality': '',
'Fine Focus dac': '2337\n',
'Diagonal Stigmator dac': '1813        Axis',
'measured spotsize      ': '0.024 um',
'PMHV setting (dac)': '2602\n',
'BEAMPAR setting        ': '300.0 s'}

Comment: For the line `bias voltage           :  -400.00  V     filament current    :     2.31  A` how do you know if it is `bias voltage  ->  -400.00  V` and `filament current -> 2.31  A` or `bias voltage -> -400.00  V     filament` and `current  -> 2.31  A`? It would seem that we would need to know the offset where the "second column" starts.

Comment: Well that's part of the problem. I know that it's the former from context and using the tool, but having regex recognise that is hard... I'm not a programmer nor well versed in regex so I'm finding this a very difficult task.

Answer (score -1):

Modify the regex pattern and convert the numbers to floats, and modify a couple other things like modifying the regex pattern and using `re.findall` instead of `re.match`

```
import re

fname = 'example.log'

colon_data = r'\s*([\w\s().]+)\s*:\s*([-\d.]+)(?:\s*[a-zA-Z]+)?(?:\s{2,}|$)'
cols = []

pat = re.compile(colon_data)

with open(fname, encoding='utf8') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

data_dict = {}
for line in contents:
    matches = re.findall(colon_data, line)
    for match in matches:
        key, value = match
        data_dict[key.strip()] = float(value) if '.' in value or '-' in value else int(value)

data_dict
```

Comment: Neither you nor the OP appear to be using `cols` (from `cols = []`) or `pat` (from `pat = re.compile(colon_data)`). Can you show your output for the string in the OP's example?

Comment: This is better than what I managed. It missed some things like date and some other features of the log files which I hadn't but clearly should have included in the MWE. I've updated the example to reflect this. Any idea how to handle things when the log file switches to a different table style like what I've added to the example?

Comment: Editing the question to move the goalposts is not really acceptable here. Perhaps roll back your change, accept this answer, and post a new question with your _actual_ requirements.